# Django: Avoid duplicates image uploads from admin panel

Tags: django

I have a model with an ImageField, which allow an image upload from the panel admin of Django.
I would like to check if the image already exists, before saving the model.

If it's the case, I would like to display a popup (or a warning on the same page) with both images, to allow users to compare images, and allow saving if it's a false positive.

For the image comparison, I'm going to use [imagehash.average_hash()](https://pypi.org/project/ImageHash/) algorithm which gaves me good results from my tests.

So my questions are:

1. How to get the file content (to compute the aHash), before the model save.
2. How to display a popup or modify the modelAdmin page to allow the check of false positive.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out to achieve this a part of this:

admin.py

```
# called after page validation, to switch page (we catch the ValidationError send from save_model
# if this image was already uploaded
def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    try:
        return super(MediaAdmin, self).changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
    except ValidationError as e:
        self.message_user(request, e, level=messages.ERROR)
        if object_id:
            # if we are editing an existing media
            return redirect(to=reverse('admin:web_app_media_change', args=(object_id, )))
        else:
            # if we try to add a new media
            return redirect(to=reverse('admin:web_app_media_add'))

# check if the media was uploaded before, and raise a ValidationError if it's the case
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if not obj.hash:
        obj.hash = imagehash.average_hash(Image.open(obj.media)).__str__()

    duplicate = False
    for media in Media.objects.all():
        if media.media != obj.media and media.hash == obj.hash:
            duplicate = True

    if not duplicate:
        super(MediaAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
    else:
        raise ValidationError("This media was already uploaded.")
```

With a new `hash = models.CharField(max_length=20)` in my Media model.

Hoping it will help :)